# String compare in C for a password

Tags: c, string-comparison, strcmp

```
void main()
{
    Password();
}


int Password()
{
    // Declare local variables//
    char cPassCode[] = "String";
    int iFlag, iComparison = 0;

    // Run the code to check the password//
    while (iFlag = 0)
    {
        printf("Please enter the password: ");
        scanf("%s", cPassCode);
        iComparison = strcmp(cPassCode, "A23bc5");
        if (iComparison = 0)
        {
            ArrayPrinter(Array);
            iFlag = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Wrong password");
            iFlag = 0;
        }
        return(iFlag);
    }
}
```

I edited the section of code and as far as I can tell it should run properly when the password A23bc5 is entered. However it is always returning a wrong password. Any ideas?

Comment: Print out the value of each char of cPassCode.

Comment: It's printing the proper password but still saying the password is incorect

Comment: **never** use strcmp() when checking a password because this makes your application vulnerable to timing attacks!  To prevent this, you can create a md5/sha hash of both the input and the real password and compare this..

Comment: Note: With passwords, best to zero scrub the buffers afterwards.  Yet with code that has an embedded `"A23bc5"`, this security improvement is moot as well as [@ensc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360641/string-compare-in-c-for-a-password#comment60341340_36360641) good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (iComparison = 0)
```

Is assigning 0 to the variable and then testing it, and 0 evaluates to false.

```
 if (iComparison == 0)
```

Is checking if the variable is 0, which is probably what you meant

Comment: Does nobody turn on warnings any more?  :((

Comment: @MartinJames usually people that are new at programming do not know how to use an IDE properly, which makes sense. They already have a hard time with the language itself :P

Comment: @MartinJames: from my experience, the problem is more often ignoring the warnings

Comment: Yup that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`strcmp` function returns 0 if the strings are equal. You should edit the condition block.

Edit:

Actually you have also very basic syntax problems.

```
  int Password()
{
//declare local variables//
char cPassCode[] = "String";
int iFlag=0, iComparison = 0;

//Run the code to check the password//
while (iFlag == 0)
{
    printf("Please enter the password: ");
    scanf("%s", cPassCode);
    iComparison = strcmp(cPassCode,"A23bc5");
    if (iComparison == 0)
    {
        printf("\n Accepted");
        iFlag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong password");
        iFlag = 0;
    }
    return(iFlag);
}
}

int main()
{


 Password();

 return 0;
}
```

This will work

Comment: It cannot be that simple - P is sure to have tried an invalid password first, surely??

Answer (score 0):

//String compare in C for a password Until 5 try//

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

int i,value;

char pass[10],id[10],key[]="1234";

printf("enter your id: ");
scanf("%s", id);

for(i=5;i>=0;i--){

printf("\nenter your password: ");
scanf("%s",pass);
value=strcmp(pass,key);

if(value==0){   
printf("matched");
return 0 ;
}

else{       
printf("not matched you have %d try left", i);
}
 }
return 0;
}
```